# Objective-c How to reload a view

Tags: objective-c, refresh, reload

I have a page which checks for internet connectivity, and then performs various actions based on the result. For example, if there is no internet connection, buttons to download files are disabled, certain buttons are not present in the navigation bar, certain text is different colour etc.

I would like to add a "refresh" button so the user can connect to the internet and reload the page.

My question is, how do I do the view refresh? Calling [self viewDidLoad]; surely isn't right, even though this is where all the logic exists. Do I need to remove the view from the superView and re-insert it or is there a way to do it without deleting?

Thanks

Comment: how do you load the view now? from `viewDidLoad`? then you can move the code to a new method 'reload' and call it instead

Comment: You should maybe move that code to some Reachability notification callback since network connection can come and go.

Comment: I did think about moving the viewDidLoad code to a new method, but the code adds elements to the page programatically based on internet connection.  If I call the method again following a click on the refresh button, all these elements will be added again... and again... and again. Sure, I could first remove all the page elements (buttons, labels, images etc) but this seems a bit counterproductive, especially considering the fact that more items will be added to the code over time. Is there not an instruction to simply reload the page?

Comment: @user857903 Check my answer and why don't you declare all your buttons in your .h file and then make buttons enable and disable accordingly. It will not make much of your code rework

Comment: I am sorry @P.J. Not sure I understand. Out of all the answers that i was able to accept, the one I ticked as an answer is the one that I will be doing... placing elements in ViewDidLoad and customising them in a new method. I know you did mention declaring them in a .h file, but I am unable to accept comments attached to my original question. what would you have ticked? Don't want to offend anyone, especially after all the help that has been offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your entire logic of Refreshing or view design in separate method and call it when you refresh it again.

```
 ViewDidLoad
  {
    [self loadViewDesign];
  [[(uibutton *) addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  }

- (void)loadViewDesign
  {
     ....
       ...
        ..
     }

 - (void)refreshData
   {
 [self loadViewDesign];
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. There is a lot to take away from this. I think using Reachability is an overkill for this instance, although I have used it before. Following the advice given, I will declare the elements in my .h file position them in my viewDidLoad, and customise them in a new method. I guess what I wanted to know is "is there a one-liner to simply reload the view", but I gather from these responses the answer is NO. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 0):

If your functionality is of checking internet and if you are using `Reachability` class of Apple,  then write

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
```

in your `viewDidLoad`,

and then write this code

```
-(void)startInternetAvailableCheck
{
    internetReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [internetReach startNotifier];
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability: internetReach];
}

-(void)updateInterfaceWithReachability:(Reachability*)curReach
{
    if(curReach == internetReach)
    {   
        NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
        switch (netStatus)
        {
            case NotReachable:
            {
                MyLog(@"Access Not Available");

                break;
            }

            case ReachableViaWWAN:
            {
                MyLog(@"Reachable WWAN");

                break;
            }
            case ReachableViaWiFi:
            {
                MyLog(@"Reachable WiFi");

                break;
            }
        }

    }
}

//Called by Reachability whenever status changes.
- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note
{
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability: curReach];
}
```

and in above mentioned `updateInterfaceWithReachability` function, you can update your view, i.e. enable and disable buttons accordingly.

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

In viewDidLoad I would create all custom UI Elements. I may even layout them there unless the layout is kinda dynamically reacting on the data itself. I would create the UIElements only once.

In a separate method, mayby named configureView I would 
- load the data (unless that is asynchonous - wich I suggest to do) 
- setup the UI elements accoringly. Set switch values, lable texts etc. 
- probably layout the elements or hide/unhide them or enalbe/disable them.

In most cases I would call configureView from viewDidLoad. Or I would call it from viewWillBecomeVisible. In that case the view is updated even when the view becomes visible when returned from any other pushed view or when switched back to it within a tab bar.

The refresh mechanism (probably an action that is linked to a button) would re-load the data and then call the configureView method too.